# Missing OK/Retry buttons on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini after video recording when started via Intent

Tags: android

I need to record a video via an Intent. On all the devices it is working fine except on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini. Here is the code:

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
mFile = FileUtils.createTempVideoFile(mContext);
if (mFile != null) {
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mFile));
    mContext.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
}
```

The video recording starts successfully but when you finish recording the OK/Cancel buttons are missing.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks and Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out what is the problem.
The only way to make it working on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (it is working just fine like that on a lot of different devices) was not to pass the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter.

Then in onActivityResult you have to query for the file name and to get it...